# Can two Hfr strains of E. coli conjugate?

Tags: genetics, bacteriology

Genetics textbooks (and some internet searching) yield abundant examples of Hfr strains conjugating with F- cells, but these sources are surprisingly silent regarding the results of an Hfr encountering another Hfr strain. Will conjugation occur in both directions, or will it not occur at all? Similarly, can F+ cells conjugate with other F+ cells?